# Retrieving index of Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

Hello I am trying to get index of current selected tab. Alert(ui.index) returns "undefined". Any idea why?

thanks

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $tabs = $("#apttabs > ul").tabs();

        $tabs.bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.index);
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="apttabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
        </ul>

    <div id="fragment-1">content 1</div>
    <div id="fragment-2">content 1</div>
    <div id="fragment-3">content 1</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you fixed it? I have the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your tabs creation code is wrong in the first place, at least it does not work for me.

It should be `var $tabs = $("#apttabs").tabs()` and then the ui.index works properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

`index` is not a defined property of the UI DOM element.  Also, what event is 'tabselect'?  It is not listed as a possible value in the [jquery bind document](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind).

Also, what do you want `index` for?  You can determine that from the event target node's href (since you've given incremental hash names in each href).

Comment: Hello Justin, thanks for your answer. "tabsselect" is listed here: 
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs 
but for some reason it doesnt work like manual says.. I need to get index of selected tab when tab is changed.

Comment: Oh right, the UI library.  I haven't used that yet so didn't think to look there.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`$tabs.tabs('option', 'selected')` instead of `ui.index`?

Comment: Hey Pawel, no, it doesn't work either. Returns [object Object].

Answer (score 0):

The 'selected' property was deprecated in 1.9 and removed in 1.10.  You need the 'active' property instead. ui.index seems to be undefined now but I haven't been able to locate documentation about its removal. http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer; If you check the date of this post, I think it'll reveal that 1.9 was not out at that time, so your information would not have applied to the OP here.